# Accessing the component from inside a custom Modifier

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a custom modifier and let's say I use it in an **Image** component, can I access that Image component from inside the modifier?

```
inline fun Modifier.pureClickable(crossinline onClick: ()->Unit): Modifier = composed {
    clickable(indication = null,
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
        onClick()
    }
}
```

The end goal is to have a custom modifier that controls the **tint** of the **Image** component on click.

Comment: Your Image component can manipulate a Modifier, not the other way around. The Modifier has no knowledge of the composable manipulating it. So no, you can't access it from within your modifier extension method

Comment: I know that's the case, but I was just wondering if there is some way around it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to update any part of the UI inside of a modifier when events cause the UI to recompose. You should stick with the design paradigm that Compose uses which is to use state variables to cause UI updates:

```kotlin
var tintColor by remember { mutableStateOf(Color(0xff000000)) }

Icon(
    modifier = Modifier
        .requiredSize(40.dp)
        .clickable {
            tintColor = Color(0xffff0000)
        },
    imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
    contentDescription = null,
    tint = tintColor
)
```